# rest-framework @detail_route without pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In rest framework exists some way to use session user instead pk and `self.get_object()` in a `@detail_route` view?

I want to use `request.user` and don't send pk in the url.

Or maybe use another decorator instead `@detail_route`...

Comment: Use @list_route instead. Detail route needs a pk by definition ( as per rest )

Comment: Can you expain a bit more about your use case maybe with some code.

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to archive in the first place. Maybe it's easier to use a separate view instead of the viewset action this case? For example here is a view snippet that lets currently logged in user manage his account:

```
class CurrentUser(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.is_active = False
        instance.save()
```

Add this to your `urlpatterns` without `pk` in the pattern:

```
    url(r'^users/me/$', CurrentUser.as_view()),
```

Comment: So where it says "me" it might be whatever you want to write there?, seems legit ! 

I'd not allow users to delete their own account, though

Comment: @LuisSieira yes, any url you want. Just no capture group since it isn't needed. It doesn't *delete* it just sets is_active to False as recommended by Django. Obviously, you can remove or change this logic as you like, this is just an example

Comment: @LuisSieira What was wrong with my answer? This answer is also using `self.request.user`

Comment: @KishorPawar It doesn't look semantically correct to retrieve the information of a single user, using a class representing "a collection of model instances", which is the reason why the OP was trying to use detail_route and not list_route, and why I opened the bounty.

Comment: @LuisSieira Ah! Got it

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I am using both plain Django and Django-rest-framework and I am using `request.user` as below.

```
class ProfileRunCounts(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.request.user
```

**update** after comments.

> HttpRequest.user
>   From the AuthenticationMiddleware: An instance of AUTH_USER_MODEL representing the currently logged-in user. If the user isn’t currently logged in, user will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser.
>
> REST framework's Request class extends the standard HttpRequest, adding support for REST framework's flexible request parsing and request authentication.
>
> APIView classes are different from regular View classes in the following ways:
>
> Requests passed to the handler methods will be REST framework's Request instances, not Django's HttpRequest instances.

With above extract from the documentation I believe user object is always available in request.
Sometimes it is in `self.request.user` and sometimes it is in `request.user`.

Comment: These are used for read-write endpoints to represent a collection of model instances, so still the same hacky feeling. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use an api_view