# Using http methods with django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, api, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm looking for some advice on how to correctly use my DRF API I have built, specifically the PATCH method at present. I am trying to formulate a script to patch the quantity of a Product / Cart Item that has been successfully added to the cart but I cannot get it to work.

For context of my project: My goal of the scripts are to be able to create a Cart, use a button to either add and Item or remove an Item (-1 quantity), Once the customer clicks a proceed to payment button the cart items are then transfered into the Order model So I can then process the order. Once order status is complete, cart is deleted and recreated.

Here is my current script:

```
const updateBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".update-cart");
const user = "{{request.user}}";
for (let i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from refreshing
    const productId = this.dataset.product;
    const action = this.dataset.action;
    console.log("productId:", productId, "action:", action);
    console.log("USER:", user);
    createCart(productId, action);
  });
}
function createCart(productId, action, cartId) {
  var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
  console.log("User is logged in, sending data...");
  fetch("/get_cart_id/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const cartId = data.cart_id;
      console.log("Cart ID:", cartId); // log cartId in console

      let method, url;
      if (action === "add") {
        method = "POST";
        url = `/api/carts/${cartId}/items/`;
      } else if (action === "remove") {
        method = "PATCH";

        url = `/api/carts/${cartId}/items/${THIS_IS_WHERE_I_NEED_ITEM_ID}/`;
      } else {
        console.log(`Invalid action: ${action}`);
        return;
      }

      fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          product_id: productId,
          quantity: 1,
        }),
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(`Item ${action}ed in cart:`, data);
        });
    });
}
```

Here are my Serializera relating to my cart(please ask for me if you require more info to assist me):

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = SimpleProductSerializer()
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_price(self, cart_item:CartItem):
        return cart_item.quantity * cart_item.product.price
    
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'product', 'quantity', 'total_price']

 CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    items = CartItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_price(self, cart):
        return sum([item.quantity * item.product.price for item in cart.items.all()])

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'items', 'total_price']
    
class AddCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate_product_id(self, value):
        if not Product.objects.filter(pk=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('No product with the given ID was found.')
        return value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        cart_id = self.context['cart_id']
        product_id = self.validated_data['product_id']
        quantity = self.validated_data['quantity']

        try: 
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(cart_id=cart_id, product_id=product_id)
            cart_item.quantity += quantity
            cart_item.save()
            self.instance = cart_item
        except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
            self.instance = CartItem.objects.create(cart_id=cart_id, **self.validated_data)
        
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'product_id', 'quantity']

class UpdateCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['quantity']
```

Finally here are my viewsets:

```
class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin,
                  RetrieveModelMixin,
                  DestroyModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('items__product').all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
 
class CartItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']
   
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return AddCartItemSerializer 
        elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
            return UpdateCartItemSerializer
        return CartItemSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'cart_id': self.kwargs['cart_pk']}

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CartItem.objects \
                .filter(cart_id=self.kwargs['cart_pk']) \
                .select_related('product')
```

This is my view that I created to retrieve the cart that is related to the current user which is created when they enter the home/gallery/product page:

```py
def get_cart_id(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
        cart_id = cart.id
        return JsonResponse({'cart_id': cart_id})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'User is not authenticated'})
```

Comment: I would [use `get_queryset` to define your user-based filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user) .  You can then [set the default permission policy](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) to disallow unauthenticated users.    So far, what I'm seeing in your code doesn't need a custom view.  I'd take a look at instantiating a cart ModelViewSet as in the [url examples](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#urls)

Comment: See also [ModelViewSet](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Comment: Oh really, thats very interesting thank you, would it be possible for you to post a snippet for me to investigate, I am very intrigued to learn and appreciate your time massively. For example; I'm not quite sure how I would use a query set to automatically create a cart for authenticated users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend moving `if (action === "...")` checks a bit higher in the nesting. It should simplify your code greatly, even if you need to make it longer by repeating `fetch("/get_cart_id/")`, it will be easier to follow.
Even better would be to separate the actions into different functions.

After you create an item using `POST`, if successful, the response will contain an id of your freshly created item. You can use that id to remove the item. The  method should be `DELETE` and not `PATCH`.

```js
function createCart(productId, action, cartId) {
  // ...
  
  if (action === "add") {
    fetch("/get_cart_id/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // ...

      fetch(`/api/carts/${cartId}/items/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        // ...
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // Save data.id somewhere
        console.log(`Created Item with id: ${data.id}`);
      });
    });
  }
  else if (action === "remove") {
    // Use saved id there
    fetch(`/api/carts/${cartId}/items/${SAVED_ID_OF_THE_ITEM_TO_REMOVE}/`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      // ...
    })
    .then(...)
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

One last thing, you should be storing your `cart_id`, since, I imagine, it's not something that's going to change, and you shouldn't fetch it every time you want to add a product.

Comment: Brilliant advice, would you have any idea of how to Make a post to create a cart, I know the route but the difficulty I'm facing is making the Cart the only one a User can have until that cart has been turning into an Order. Currently a new cart is been made regardless of a user already having one

Comment: I see. You can add [`@action(detail=False)`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) to your viewset. You can call it `current`, which will result in `/api/carts/current` or you might use a separate view - [for inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159125/723891)

Comment: I am using a separate view currently, I was just hoping to make full use of my API with http methods but I am struggling with the cart creation

Comment: So, what's wrong with using `POST` for it?

Comment: It isn't working, I cant get it to work with a get_or_create method as I only want one user to have one cart at a time

Comment: Have you seen the example I linked that allows managing currently logged-in user? You can change the model to Cart. add a `get_or_create` to `get_object` and that should do it for you. Basically, don't think about creating as a separate action, just get the user's cart using GET and, if doesn't exist it will be created by `get_or_create`

Comment: I didn't even notice the link, apologies. I will look now.